# How to partition MYSQL with YEAR MONTH DAY HOUR as partition form timestamp column

Tags: mysql, partition

I am trying to recreate a AWS Athena table in MYSQL with similar partitions as shown below.

[image]

The partitions are as follows

```
partition_0 = YEAR
partition_1 = Month
partition_2 = Day
partition_3 = Hour
```

How can I achieve this in MYSQL. The table has a time stamp column.

Would the table create query look like this

```
CREATE TABLE newTable (
    column var not null,
    .
    .
    .
    timestamp DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (column)
    )
    PARTITION BY LIST (timestamp)(
        PARTITION YEAR VALUES IN ( YEAR(timestamp))
        PARTITION MONTH VALUES IN ( MONTH(timestamp))
        PARTITION DAY VALUES IN  ( DAY(timestamp))
        PARTITION HOUR VALUES IN (HOUR(timestamp))
    )
```

I am thinking a RANGE would be better than a LIST but not exactly sure how I can break range into Hours days months and years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement that is similar to Athena table partition. You need to adjust the syntax and data type as per MySQL standard.

```
CREATE TABLE newTable  (
    column var not null,
   --
   --
   --

   timestamp DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (column)
)
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(timestamp) (
     PARTITION YEAR VALUES IN ( YEAR(timestamp))
        PARTITION MONTH VALUES IN ( MONTH(timestamp))
        PARTITION DAY VALUES IN  ( DAY(timestamp))
        PARTITION HOUR VALUES IN (HOUR(timestamp))
);
```

For more details , see this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-columns-list.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](http://anothermysqldba.blogspot.com/2014/12/a-mysql-partition-and-subpartition.html) on the web. I kinda explained how to partition and sub partition into months. Then I realized by I were to sub partition into days that will be one long partition query. And the query would have to run every year.

The best course of action it seems to partition by year, at least for me to start with. And then see if there is a need to partition by month.

I am also learning that in the query if I use BETWEEN or <= / >= the results are much faster than LIKE queries.

Thanks for your help.